# Refactoring animation to use Task.Delay instead of Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

While learning async/await in C#, I'm trying to change a WPF custom progress bar to use Task.Delay instead of a Timer to animate it. The problem is that the progress bar appears to be stuck on the "first frame" of the animation.

It does work if don't call Animate() using Task.Run() but then I get the warning **Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.** and I can't use await in the Activate() method without making it async which in turn would mean making the whole chain of methods async which seems odd. The other alternative to avoid the warning would be to make the Animate() method *async void* instead of *async Task* but this seems to be strongly advised against from what I've read so far.

What's the best practice to solve this?

```
public class IndeterminateProgressBar : System.Windows.Controls.Control
{
    private bool _active = false;
    private Ellipse _c0;
    private Ellipse _c1;
    private Ellipse _c2;
    private Ellipse _c3;
    private Ellipse _c4;
    private Ellipse _c5;
    private Ellipse _c6;
    private Ellipse _c7;
    private Ellipse _c8;
    private RotateTransform _spinnerRotate;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Active", typeof(bool), typeof(IndeterminateProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(IndeterminateProgressBar_OnActivePropertyChanged)));
    private static void IndeterminateProgressBar_OnActivePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IndeterminateProgressBar indeterminateProgressBar = dObj as IndeterminateProgressBar;
        indeterminateProgressBar.Active = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
    public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ActiveProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ActiveProperty, value);
            ChangeState(value);
        }
    }

    static IndeterminateProgressBar()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IndeterminateProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(IndeterminateProgressBar)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _c0 = GetTemplateChild("Part0") as Ellipse;
        _c1 = GetTemplateChild("Part1") as Ellipse;
        _c2 = GetTemplateChild("Part2") as Ellipse;
        _c3 = GetTemplateChild("Part3") as Ellipse;
        _c4 = GetTemplateChild("Part4") as Ellipse;
        _c5 = GetTemplateChild("Part5") as Ellipse;
        _c6 = GetTemplateChild("Part6") as Ellipse;
        _c7 = GetTemplateChild("Part7") as Ellipse;
        _c8 = GetTemplateChild("Part8") as Ellipse;
        _spinnerRotate = GetTemplateChild("Spinner") as RotateTransform;

        const double offset = Math.PI;
        const double step = Math.PI * 2 / 10.0;

        SetPosition(_c0, offset, 0.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c1, offset, 1.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c2, offset, 2.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c3, offset, 3.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c4, offset, 4.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c5, offset, 5.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c6, offset, 6.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c7, offset, 7.0, step);
        SetPosition(_c8, offset, 8.0, step);
    }

    private void SetPosition(Ellipse ellipse, double offset, double posOffSet, double step)
    {
        ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 50.0 + Math.Sin(offset + posOffSet * step) * 50.0); ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 50 + Math.Cos(offset + posOffSet * step) * 50.0);
    }

    private async Task Animate()
    {
        while (_active)
        {
            if (_spinnerRotate != null)
                _spinnerRotate.Angle = (_spinnerRotate.Angle + 36) % 360;

            await Task.Delay(75);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeState(bool active)
    {
        if (active)
            Activate();
        else
            Deactivate();
    }

    private void Activate()
    {
        if (!_active)
        {
            _active = true;

            Task.Run(async () => await Animate());

            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void Deactivate()
    {
        if (_active)
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            _active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to make the whole method chain async/await. That's the principle of this pattern.

Comment: @Sebi but then what do I do with the Active property that calls the methods? it can't be async: **The modifier 'async' is not valid for this item**

Comment: You shouldn't need a async property. Property is designed to be lightweight. Doing heavy work in a Property is not recommended. You could make an async method which set the Property. User of your class need to await this method and after that they can access your property.

Comment: Ok, I put the method call in the OnActivePropertyChanged callback for the Active property but now this callback method needs to be async void to be able to await. If I'm gonna use async void which everyone advises against, I might as well use it on the Animate() method directly. Perhaps it's not viable to use async/wait in this case. The progress bar is triggered by the property binding in the XAML so there's no method that can be awaited in a controlled way.

Comment: The await keyword is certainly not always the best solution.  It is not when you can also easily do this with a DispatcherTimer or a Storyboard.

Comment: "If I'm gonna use async void which everyone advises against" - it's advised against for almost everything _except_ event handlers, where it is appropriate.

Comment: use a background worker, then use the progress method to update your UI